# How to Handle Form in React Native with a Single Handler Function using React Hooks

Tags: android, reactjs, react-hooks, react-native

I have a form with many TextInput field and I want to use a single handler function for each onChangeText prop.

It was easy in react as we can set state with [name] = value because handler gives us the event but in react native it gives us the value of the TextInput field.

My example is like this -

```
export const myForm = () => {
const [form, setForm] = useState({name: '', number: '', address: '' })

const onChangeHandler = (value) => {
  // how to handle for each state field
 }
return (
<View>
   <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text>Product Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={form.name}
        name="name"
        onChangeText={onChangeHandler}
      ></TextInput>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text>Product Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={form.number}
        name="number"
        onChangeText={onChangeHandler}
      ></TextInput>
   </View>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text>Product Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={form.address}
        name="address"
        onChangeText={onChangeHandler}
      ></TextInput>
   </View>
   <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.6}
      onPress={saveForm}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>SUBMIT</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
<View> )}
```

Is there any way this can be done with React Hooks. Looked everywhere but didn't find a solution.
I know how to handle this form with class based components, I am not able to understand how can I achieve this with React Hooks.
Please HELP!!!

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with hooks. Please confirm what is the return type of onChangeText. If its value then there is a different approach to this, but if its an HTML event then there might be some other issue

Comment: As i mentioned, onChangeText return the value which we enter in the text field. It doesn't return event in React Native. My question was how do I update the state of setForm for every TextInput field.

Comment: Can you use `onChange` instead on `onChangeText`? `onChange` returns `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }`. [Link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this. Thanks RossHochwert for the help. I just passed another argument in onChangeHandler, same as the property name which I used in useState.

```
export const myForm = () => {
 const [form, setForm] = useState({name: '', number: '', address: '' })

 const onChangeHandler = (value, name) => {
  // how to handle for each state field
  setForm(form => ({
    ...form,
    [name]: value
  }))
 }
return (
 <View>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
   <Text>Product Name</Text>
   <TextInput
    value={form.name}
    onChangeText={(value) => onChangeHandler(value, "name")}
   ></TextInput>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
  <Text>Product Name</Text>
   <TextInput
    value={form.number}
    onChangeText={(value) => onChangeHandler(value, "number")}
   ></TextInput>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
   <Text>Product Name</Text>
   <TextInput
    value={form.address}
    onChangeText={(value) => onChangeHandler(value, "address")}
    ></TextInput>
  </View>
 <TouchableOpacity
  activeOpacity={0.6}
  onPress={saveForm}
 >
  <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>SUBMIT</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
<View> )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you pass the name of the form to your onChangeHandler along with the text input?

You could also use try using onChange instead of onChangeText?

```
const onChangeHandler = (name, value) => {
  if(name=="address"){
    //setState(value)
  } else if (name=="number"){
    //setState(value)
  }
 }
```

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text>Product Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={form.name}
        name="name"
        onChangeText={(value)=>onChangeHandler(name,value)}
      ></TextInput>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text>Product Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={form.number}
        name="number"
        onChangeText={(value)=>onChangeHandler(name,value)}
      ></TextInput>
   </View>
```